# grep pipe sed commands

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipe

Here is the stat result for "file1.txt"

```
`File: 'file1.txt'
  Size: 477             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d      Inode: 55599980    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    marc)   Gid: ( 1000/    
marc)
Access: 2018-04-19 19:19:01.708143285 +0200
Modify: 2018-04-19 19:18:58.216117199 +0200
Change: 2018-04-19 19:18:58.216117199 +0200
Birth: -`
```

I want to get the "Modify" line with grep:

```
`stat file1.txt | grep Modify
Modify: 2018-04-19 19:18:58.216117199 +0200`
```

I would like now to insert this line before first line of file1.txt.

I would use a command like:

```
`stat file1.txt | grep Modify | sed -i '1 i\"result_of_grep"' file1.txt`,
```

but don't know how to tell the shell to use the result of the preceding grep dommand (what i called "result_of_grep").

Thanks in advance...

Comment: why not insert the line before grep?

Comment: `stat -c '%y' file1.txt`

Comment: Don't use `sed -i` for this.  Just do `{ stat -c '%y' file1.txt; cat file1.txt; } > file2.txt`.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I would like to get the interesting line in my file1.txt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed -i "1i\\
#$(stat file1.txt | grep Modify)
" file1.txt
```

Comment: If I would like also to paste "#" before "Modify" ?